# making a friend system in node js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am building an app where my users can have friends and I store them in a table like this

**uid |  ownerUid | friendUid**

and then I have a users database like this

**uid | username | password**

and I am trying to make a system to where the user enters the uid of a user into a text box and it adds him as a friend if he is a user and if he is not already his friend using this code

```
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?", [friendToAddUid], function(err, rows) {
        if(rows){
            rows.forEach(function(row) {
                //is an actual person
                        connection.query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE ownerUid = ?", [uid], function(err, rows) {
                                    if(rows){
                                    console.log("user exist")
                                        rows.forEach(function(row){
                                            if (row.friendUid = friendToAddUid){
                                            }else{
                                                var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US") + ", " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US");
                                                var row = [ uniqid(), uid, friendToAddUid, timestamp];
                                                connection.query('INSERT INTO friends SET uid=?, ownerUid=?, friendUid=?, since=?', row, function(err) {
                                                    console.log(err)
                                                });
                                            }
                                        })
                                        if(rows.length <= 0){
                                            var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US") + ", " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US");
                                            var row = [ uniqid(), uid, friendToAddUid, timestamp];
                                            connection.query('INSERT INTO friends SET uid=?, ownerUid=?, friendUid=?, since=?', row, function(err) {
                                                console.log(err)
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        var timestamp = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US") + ", " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US");
                                        var row = [ uniqid(), uid, friendToAddUid, timestamp];
                                        connection.query('INSERT INTO friends SET uid=?, ownerUid=?, friendUid=?, since=?', row, function(err) {
                                            console.log(err)
                                        });
                                    }
                        })
            })
        }
    })
```

it adds the user fine and won't add him if he is already your friend but I cant add any more friends after I add one friend and I don't know why

wanted to know if there is an issue with my MySQL query

Comment: These are tables (not databases). What's the difference between uid and owneruid? How do you want to handle reciprocation?

Comment: Note that in your code you sometimes spell 'friend' correctly, and sometimes you don't. Code likes consistency.

Comment: @Strawberry the uid is the unique id of the row